# How to set .env file in Jupyter lab notebook react app

Tags: reactjs, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm creating an jupyter lab extension using react where Ive to use api that fetches the the results. Now that api needs private key, which generally in a normal react app, can be stored in an .env file at the root directory. I've done the same in the case of Jupyter lab, but it returns undefined. So, is there some kindof different approach that I need to make in jupyter lab, or am i missing something ?

I've created .env file, stored the private key, and built the jupyter lab by using jlpm run build. But upon console logging process.env.API_KEY, it returns undefined.

Comment: `process.env` is something provided by node and you shouldn't expect that to be available for statically compiled assets served outside of node.  You'll likely need to compile them in or write/find a server extension to rewrite it as it's being served.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, `process.env` is provided by node when it is being used to serve the react app. In your case, jupyter (i.e. python) is being used to serve the react extension and so the `process` variable isn't defined.

The solution is to add a server portion to your extension that can use python's `os.environ` to get the environment variable. Then you need to write a small API with a route handler that can share the environment variable with a `get` request. You'll want to follow the [jupyter server-extension example](https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/tree/main/server-extension) to get everything rigged up correctly.

**Example**

Here is a minimal example pulled almost directly from the tutorial linked above.

You should add a `handlers.py` file in your extension directory and add at least one route handler to share the environment variables you need. Here's a minimal example of what would be in that file:

```
import json
import os

from jupyter_server.base.handlers import APIHandler
from jupyter_server.utils import url_path_join
import tornado


class MyRouteHandler(APIHandler):
    # The following decorator should be present on all verb methods (head, get, post,
    # patch, put, delete, options) to ensure only authorized user can request the
    # Jupyter server
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.finish(json.dumps({
            "data": os.environ.get("REACT_APP_API_KEY", None),
        }))


def setup_handlers(web_app):
    host_pattern = ".*$"

    base_url = web_app.settings["base_url"]
    web_app.add_handlers(host_pattern, [
        (url_path_join(base_url, "name-of-your-extension", "my_route"), MyRouteHandler)
    ])
```

Then in your react extension code you should add a `handler.ts` file that sets up requests to the jupyter server API you created:

```
import { URLExt } from '@jupyterlab/coreutils';
import { ServerConnection } from '@jupyterlab/services';

/**
 * Call the API extension
 *
 * @param endPoint API REST end point for the extension
 * @param init Initial values for the request
 * @returns The response body interpreted as JSON
 */
export async function requestAPI(
  endPoint = '',
  init = {}
) {
  // Make request to Jupyter API
  const settings = ServerConnection.makeSettings();
  const requestUrl = URLExt.join(
    settings.baseUrl,
    'name-of-your-extension', // API Namespace
    endPoint
  );

  let response;
  try {
    response = await ServerConnection.makeRequest(requestUrl, init, settings);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new ServerConnection.NetworkError(error as any);
  }

  let data: any = await response.text();

  if (data.length > 0) {
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Not a JSON response body.', response);
    }
  }

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new ServerConnection.ResponseError(response, data.message || data);
  }

  return data;
}
```

Then you can use the `requestAPI` function somewhere in your react app to get the environment variable from the route you created:

```
import { requestAPI } from './handler';

export const environmentData = {};

requestAPI('my_route')
    .then(data => {
        environmentData.apiKey = data;
    })
    .catch(reason => {
      console.error(
        `The name_of_your_extension server extension appears to be missing.\n${reason}`
      );
    });
```

It seems like a lot for something that sounds simple but this is the way that seems to be recommended.

[Here is a relevant thread from the jupyter discourse forum.](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/read-environment-variables-from-jupyter/8878/2)

Comment: @Pronil07 just following up, does this solve your issue?